# Simple Quadratic function exercise

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, quadratics

I am a math teacher and I want to have some other opinions regarding an exercise made from one of my colleagues because I think that she was wrong when correcting the solutions from her students.

The exercise is the following - it's rather easy:

Which **two** of the following answers are correct when considering the following function

`f(x)=a*x^2+b` with `a > 0` and `b < 0`:

(A) *f* intersects with the y-axis at the point P(0|*b*).
(B) *f* has two roots.
(C) The bigger *b* is the steeper is the graph of *f*.
(D) The smaller *a* is the more flat is the graph of *f*.
(E) *f* has a maximum.

Comment: Certainly (A) and (B)  are correct and (C),(E) are false. When do you call a graph "flat"?

Comment: (E) is false always. (C) is not precisely phrased and comes close to nonsense; but, I imagine the intended answer is "not correct".

Comment: @Listing maybe the term `smooth` is more appropriate than `flat` .. since I am German speaking I am lacking some of the English mathematical terms ...

Comment: If one interprets "flat" literally, then (C) is "not correct", since a quadratic function is flat nowhere regardless of the value of the leading coeficient.

Comment: I would interpret the flatness of a function as $\text{diam}(f(\mathbb{R}))$ in which case (C) and (D) would be false as in every case for $a$ the diameter is $\infty$.

Comment: If "flat" means "less steep," then D *is* correct. A decrease in $a$ corresponds to a vertical contraction. Options A and B are certainly true. Which options did your colleague claim to be correct?

Comment: @CameronBuie The student checked answers (A) and (B) and my colleague said both of them are false but she did not provide which two answers were the correct ones. The student then came to me and I did assure her that answers (A) and (B) are correct for sure (as she checked during the exam) as well as answer (D) iff, flat refers to a smaller slope of the graph. I did argue in the exact same way as you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(A) and (B) are true.  For a given value $x$ the slope is smaller there in absolute value as $a$ becomes smaller (but remains positive), so (D) is also true in that sense.  (C) and (E) are false.

I suppose one can argue about which of the statements are "most true".  The interpretation of (D) is the most subjective.

Answer (score 2):

- What does `f(x)=0` tell us? Indeed  `a>0, b<0` makes `x` to be `x_0=+\sqrt{b/a}` and `x_1=-\sqrt{b/a}` so the function intersect $x$ axis at two reals.
- If `x=0` then `f(0)=b` so the intersection point with $y$ axis is `(0,b)`.
- `a>0` so the curve is upward, so the last option is wrong.

Comment: Thank you .. your help is pretty much appreciated!